# Android cant recover state

Tags: android

So I have been looking at tutorials and messing with things for hours. I have my main activity which creates a map of object that it gets from the database. To avoid unnecessary database queries, I am trying to save that map using the `onSaveInstanceState` method and then restore it with the `onRestoreInstanceState`. I can see that it gets saved correctly using the debugger, but if I set break points in the `onRestoreInstaceState` method the program never breaks. Then I thought I would just do it with the `onCreate()` method but it's not breaking there either. The program should break in both of those places when returning from a different activity right?

Answer (score 1):

Those two methods are only called if the activity is killed and restarted.

The good news is, if your activity was *not* killed, there's no need to restore your state. It should still be just the way it was.

If you *do* need to do something when switching back from another Activity, that's what `onResume()` is for.

See [the chart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more.

Comment: Well when i get back to my main activity, my map keys are still intact, but the objects they point to are empty. The string values are  "" and the int values are -1. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what they are and how they're used. That may be a topic for a separate question, though. That way you can get more specific answers for that case.

Comment: Will do. Thanks. +1 for the advise.

Comment: Hey Geo would activity restore after calling finish?